# How to transform the following logical expression into English

Tags: logic

I don't fully understand the semantics of changing logical expressions into English

Transform the following predicate calculus statements into English. Let
$A(x)$ represent the statement that $x$ is an accountant, $B(x)$ represent the
statement that $x$ is a businessman, $E(x)$ represent the statement that $x$
is an engineer, and $M(x, y)$ represent the statement that $x$ manages $y$.

1. $\forall x\exists y, A(x) \vee E(x) \implies B(y) \wedge M(y, x)$
2. $\exists x\forall y\exists z, E(x) \wedge (A(y) \wedge M(y, x) \implies M(y, z))$

For example, I thought that the first statement is:`For all people who are either an accountant or an engineer there is a businessman who manages them.`

Does this statement need to include a different grammatical structure like so:`For all people who are either an accountant or an engineer there is a businessman who manages him or her.`

And then I thought that the second statement would be `All people who are accountants and manage an engineer also manage another person.` But I am not sure if that makes sense given that $E(x)$ is outside of the expression $(A(y) \wedge M(y, x) \implies M(y, z))$ where $M(y,x)$ dictates that $y$ manages $x$.

Comment: More like there is an engineer such as for every accountant who manages this engineer,there is a person who the accountant manages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the two translations of 1. are quite equivalent : "them" can be "him or her" (but I'm not and English speaker ...).

But take into account that $\forall$ means "all" but without necessarily assuming that "all" must be "more than one".

So, can be better to read the formual as : "everyone which is an accountant or an engineer is managed by a businessman ".

---

For 2. :

> $∃x∀y∃z,E(x)∧(A(y)∧M(y,x) \Rightarrow M(y,z))$

we have first an *Engineer* : $∃x,E(x)$.

Then we have a condition on the *Accountants* who manage him : $∀y∃z,(A(y)∧M(y,x) \Rightarrow M(y,z))$ that is :

> for all $y$, if $y$ is an *Accountant* and *Manages* $x$, then $y$ *Manages* $z$, for some $z$.

Putting all togetehr :

> There is an *Engineer* and all *Accountant* that *Manages* him, *Manages* someone.

The two existential quantifiers $\exists x$ and $\exists z$ do not force us to choose different person  : see your "another person".

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is fine and very intuitive. However, I don't understand what scope of the quatifiers you have in mind (isn't an open parenthesis missing?). If your scope is the whole expression, your second example is nice, except that $E(x)$ must be inside the parenthesis, as you've noticed himself. Good work!